# WPF - Combine xmlns

Tags: wpf, xml-namespaces, assemblyinfo

1) I have 3 assemblies. A,B and UI

2) B references A.

3) UI references B and A.

4) in A's AssemblyInfo.cs

```
     [assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.cmp.com/a", "A.Controls")]
```

5) in B's AssemblyInfo.cs

```
     [assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.cmp.com/b", "B.Controls.Extensions")]
```

6) In my UI i have a view

```
<UserControl  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:a="http://www.cmp.com/a"
    xmlns:b="http://www.cmp.com/b">

  <TextBox a:TextBoxExtensions.Ext1="Red"
           b:TextBoxExtensions.Ext1="Blue" />

</UserControl>
```

Is there any way i could combine both "http://www.cmp.com/a" and "http://www.cmp.com/b" under the same xmlns or atlist under the same prefix ?

Comment: 1. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. Have you tried putting the same value in the XmlnsDefinition attributes of A and B?

Comment: Ive tried 2 before. and now i did it again and it did work... strange..
1) I want to sometimes use A only and when also using B other capabilities
Magically appear .

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you just need to map both namespaces to the same URL:

- in A's AssemblyInfo.cs

  ```
  [assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.cmp.com/controls", "A.Controls")]
  ```
- in B's AssemblyInfo.cs

  ```
  [assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://www.cmp.com/controls", "B.Controls.Extensions")]
  ```

Then you only have to declare one XMLNS to access types from both namespaces:

```
xmlns:controls="http://www.cmp.com/controls"
```